# Chrome update, AngularJS issue

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, ng-show

I'm working on a kind of a big AngularJS project. After updating Google Chrome to version 33.0.1750.117, ng-show makes the whole page to blink. I mean, when it becames true, before the div becames visible (even if it's a small div) the **whole** page blinks. And in many cases it blinks *every time* I toggle ng-show between true and false (with a toggle button).

Before the update it worked just fine. **In firefox and Opera it still works as it should**.

I tried with ng-cloak but I think is has nothing to do.

BTW, I'm using ng-animate. This is the code:

```
.animate_fade {
   -webkit-transition: linear 0.2s all;
   -moz-transition: linear 0.2s all;
   -ms-transition: linear 0.2s all;
   -o-transition: linear 0.2s all;
   transition: linear 0.2s all;
}

.animate_fade.ng-hide-add,
.animate_fade.ng-hide-remove {
   display:block!important;
}

.animate_fade.ng-hide-add {
   opacity:1;
}

.animate_fade.ng-hide-add-active {
   opacity:0;
}

.animate_fade.ng-hide-remove {
   opacity:0;
}

.animate_fade.ng-hide-remove-active {
   opacity:1;
}
```

Any clue?

Thanks in advance,

Bruno.

Comment: Difficult to guess without any code snippets. Do you use ng-animate on show & hide? Seems a css issue, so check your css.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've added the css of the animation I use.

Comment: First, which version of Angular are you using? There were some issues with animations that have been fixed recently: [Angular Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). If you're up to date, you can try using [ng-cloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to see if it fixes it.

Comment: I'm using the last version, 1.2.13. I've tried ng-cloak, but it doesn't seem to work. The whole page blinks, not only the div I'm trying to show. I have to underline the fact that **it does work fine on firefox and opera**.

Comment: Sorry, I did read about FF and Opera but missed that you've already tried ng-cloak. So, it seems to be a Chrome issue. Could you try to reproduce the problem in a simple fiddle/plunker like done here : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5262 ?

Comment: I'can't reproduce it in plunker. But if I remove the animation, it works fine.

Comment: It looks that the `display:block !important` inside the animation css is what generates the blink. But without that line, the animation doesn't work.

Comment: me too facing issue with $scope.apply by latest version of chrome

Comment: @Bruno Did you find a solution ? I have the same problem with the opacity which makes blink the whole page

Comment: @Steffi I didn't find a solution. I had a deadline so I just removed the animation.

Answer (score 0):

instead ng-show use ng-if. ng-if will bound HTML based on condition so there wont be any issues.